# Should Parallel.Foreach be waited?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

A weird thing is happening here. I thought Parallel.Foreach would wait until all of its tasks are complete before moving on. But then, I have something like that:

```
List<string> foo(List<A> list){
    Dictionary<string, bool> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    Parallel.Foreach(list, element =>
    {
        dictionary[element.Id] = true;
        if (element.SomeMethod()){
            dictionary[element.Id] = false;
        }
    });

    List<string> selectedIds = (from element in list where !dictionary[element.Id] select element.Id).ToList();
    return selectedIds;
}
```

and then I'm getting System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException (sometimes, not always) in the select line. As you can see, I'm initializing the dictionary for every possible key (Ids of list's elements), and then getting this exception, which made me think that this line might be reached before the execution of the Parallel.Foreach completes... Is that right? If so, how can I wait until all branches of this Parallel.Foreach completes?

Comment: my experience and all the sample I have seen if that the main thread blocks till the the work is fnished

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary!

Comment: And a big up for the plink example below which is also massively more readable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Parallel.Foreach` doesn't need to be waited as it doesn't return a `Task` and isn't asynchronous. When the call to that method completes the iteration is already done.

However, `Parallel.Foreach` uses multiple threads concurrently and `Dictionary` isn't thread safe.

You probably have a race conditions on your hands and you should be using the thread safe `ConcurrentDictionary` instead.

---

This specific case can be solved in a simpler way by using PLinq's `AsParallel`:

```
list.AsParallel().Where(element => !element.SomeMethod());
```